# Auto-generate user click inside primeng pagination

Tags: angular, primeng

I am using primeng's p-dataview with pagination to show user test questions.

```
<p-dataView [value]="userTestQuestions" [paginator]="true" [rows]="1" [totalRecords]="totalTestQuestions">
    <ng-template let-question pTemplate="listItem">

... html to show the question with submit button => onClick  event 

   </ng-template>
```

Currently after submit, I save the user result but user has to click on pagination to go to next question. The way I want is after submit, p-dataview automatically refreshes and goes to next page. I tried to search a lot but I am unable to find how I can auto-generate that user click inside primeng.

Currently using "primeng": "^6.1.4"

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 0):

I made a quick test, with the paginator only, showing no actual data. I added a reference to it, as shown here:

```
<p-paginator #paginatorReference [rows]="10" [totalRecords]="120" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10,20,30]"></p-paginator>
```

I then used that reference on the fake submit button in order to call the paginator internal changePage method whenever it is clicked, like this:

```
<button type="button" (click)="submitResults(); paginatorReference.changePage(paginatorReference.getPage()+1)">Press for next page</button>
```

Some refining might be needed in order to check if you're already on the last page and other possible problems, but I did not have time for further testing.

For future reference, you can check the paginator internal methods here: https://github.com/primefaces/primeng/blob/master/src/app/components/paginator/paginator.ts